# Why does Files create such large scans?

Tags: scanning, files.app

I scanned 24 pages on latest iOS, creating a 200 MB pdf. With Ghostscript and QPDF with default-like flags, I compressed it to 11 MB. Is there a way to remove bloat from the PDF created from scanned pages in the Files app without copying it to PC? Is this a bug?

Comment: Did file contain a lot of graphics?

Comment: A scan of 24 pages taken via the Scan to PDF feature in the Files app

Comment: Sorry, stupid question...

Comment: @Natsfan I don’t think it was a bad question! It could be that iOS doesn’t compress images in the scanned documents very well. I’d like to see what the answer is and whether OP’s tried just text to see how that compares?

Comment: @grg I can't try text, the Files app's "Scan option" creates only image PDFS from camera scans

Comment: True but I meant black text on mostly white should compress better than colourful images when both are stored as images. Probably not the reason but still curious.